# What's the difference between "Deploy New Contract" and "Custom Token"?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can someone please explain what the difference between Deploying a new contract versus a custom token. This is on wallet.ethereum.org and when you go to the contracts tab, you will see it there. So let's say I am working in Remix and I have finished making my token, should I use "deploy new contract" or "Custom Token" to officially release my token. I have watched a few tutorials and the different videos show some using the Deploy new contract and some show using Custom Token.

What exactly are the differences between these two and if I was to release my own Token that I made in Remix, which one should I go with?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **What exactly are the differences between these two and if I was to
  release my own Token that I made in Remix, which one should I go
  with?**

For a token, deploy with the token option, as it is made for.

But for more details, your token IS a contract. But all the contract are not tokens (thanks ICo stuff for making people thinking that...). You can have a contract that does coffee or that tells you what the weather is. It does not matter, every token in Ethereum IS a contract and IS managed by this contract.

Comment: got it, this really helped clear things up.